# If I put scrollview then layout,layout doesn't show

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I have a `dialog` that shows inside of it a `layout` in which there is a `scrollview` and another `layout` with some `buttons`. My issue is that, if I put the `layout` with the `buttons` below the scroll view it won't show. If I put it above the `scrollview` it shows. What's wrong ?

```
            LinearLayout ldialog = new LinearLayout(Gestionarez.this);
            LinearLayout ldialogb = new LinearLayout(Gestionarez.this);
            LinearLayout ldialogm = new LinearLayout(Gestionarez.this);
            ScrollView scroll = new ScrollView(Gestionarez.this);



            Space space = new Space(Gestionarez.this);
            Space space2 = new Space(Gestionarez.this);
            ldialogb.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
            ldialog.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
            ldialogm.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);

            ldialog.setPadding(20, 20, 20, 20);
            ldialogb.setPadding(20, 20, 20, 20);


            ldialogb.addView(trimitere, 130, 60);
            ldialogb.addView(space, 60, 60);
            ldialogb.addView(printeaza, 130, 60);
            ldialogb.addView(space2, 60, 60);
            ldialogb.addView(stergere, 130, 60);
            ldialogb.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER | Gravity.BOTTOM);
            Dtv.setText(text);
            Dtv.setTextSize(12);

            Dtv.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER | Gravity.BOTTOM);
            Dtv.setPadding(60, 60, 60, 60);

            scroll.addView(Dtv);

            ldialogm.addView(scroll);
            ldialogm.addView(ldialogb);

            alert.setView(ldialogm);

            dialog = alert.create();

            dialog.show();
```

Comment: "wont show" as in it is outside the bounds of the screen?

Comment: Nope,it simply doesn't show in the dialog.All that it gets showed in the dialog is the scrollview.

Comment: Try to restrict the height of the ListView to 10dp and see what happens. Just for testing.

Comment: It's a scrollview,not listview.Added it like this `ldialogm.addView(scroll,1000,1000);` .Indeed,now it shows the buttons but the scorll won't wrap content.It will be the same size no matter what is inside it.And that's messy.

Comment: I think I understand the issue, but one last question to confirm, is the layout, which has the dialog in it, a LinearLayout?

Comment: Yes.They are all LinearLayouts except for the ScrollView,of course.You can see that in the code i supplied

Answer (score 1):

You aren't setting any [`LayoutParams`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.LayoutParams.html) anywhere, so the layouts have no guidance on whether they should match their parent Views' height, wrap the content height, etc.

I would suggest using a layout XML file instead, as it will make the process of defining, using, and adjusting your layout far easier.

If you need to continue defining this in code for whatever reason, set `LayoutParams` for your Views. A View's `LayoutParams` come from the `ViewGroup` that contains them. For a View within a `LinearLayout` you should use `LinearLayout.LayoutParams`; Similarly a child View in a `RelativeLayout` uses `RelativeLayout.LayoutParams`.

In this case, you would want to use [`LinearLayout.LayoutParams`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/LinearLayout.LayoutParams.html) like so:

```
LinearLayout ldialog = new LinearLayout(Gestionarez.this);

ScrollView scroll = new ScrollView(Gestionarez.this);
LinearLayout.LayoutParams scrollLayoutParams = 
    new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
scroll.setLayoutParams(scrollLayoutParams);

ldialog.addView(scroll);
```

Comment: Added that,doesn't work.I'll do a XML layout.I started doing by code and ended up adding a lot of stuff to it,that's why i did it this way.Indeed,it's a lot better to have a XML layout.Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

I believe the issue is the Layouts. Only the ScrollView and ListView are actually scrollable, the rest will fill the possible area available in the screen, cropping the unviewable area. To wrap the dialog view withe a ScrollView and make the dialog view's height `wrap_content`.

Answer (score 0):

Well,in the end i succeded by using weight and doing this :

```
LinearLayout.LayoutParams p1 = new     LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,0);
p1.weight=20f;
LinearLayout.LayoutParams p2 = new   LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,0);
p2.weight=0.001f;

ldialogm.addView(scroll,p1);
ldialogm.addView(ldialogb,p2);
```

Comment: That is not the way to do it, and will most likely screw up the layout on small size screens, and normal size screens in landscape mode...

Comment: Yes,i know it's not the best practice but it does what i need.Ideally,i should do an xml i guess but i didn't have the time for that and the research i need to do for it.Anyway it's weird that it does that when it's below the scrollview and not when it's above it.

Comment: Hehe,i'll take care of it when i have nothing else to do,if that helps.Thanks !